# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'buildozer'

Tags: python, linux, buildozer

I am trying to install buildozer on my linux, using the steps at here: 
    https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html

When I use the command line:
    buildozer init

I got this error:

```
File "/home/kouhi/.local/bin/buildozer", line 5, in <module>
from buildozer.scripts.client import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'buildozer'
```

Any ideas to solve this problem? thankyou in advance

P.S: everything started by updating my python from 3.5 to 3.7!!!  before that everything were fine

Comment: For what it's worth, 3.7  is not listed [on its PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/buildozer/) as supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an observation, but some applications that work on python 3.6, fail on 3.7+
Most unfortunate that one of that apps is mine and there is no firm solution for some incompatibilities. I mean I had to downgrade python down to 3.6 version.
Hope it helps.

Yet, other way around is to install through pip:

```
pip search buildozer

buildozer (1.0)      - Generic Python packager for Android / iOS and Desktop
buildertron (0.1.0)  - A buildozer front-end for Linux
```

And of course

```
python -m pip install buildozer
```

There is no assurance that it will work, but at least you'll be safe on dependencies side.

Comment: Not sure if it still applies, but I saw [this comment in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51975475/4650297): "The readme in 2018 claims python3 support if you compile buildozer from source, but not from pip"